# Saturation and Associated Primes of an Ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

> If $I$ is an ideal of a Noetherian ring $S$ and $x,y\in S$, show that the following are equivalent:
>
> $(1)$    $(I:y^{\infty})=(I:(x,y)^{\infty})$
>
> $(2)$   Every associated prime of $I$ that contains $y$ also contains $x.$

$(1)\Rightarrow (2)$ is very simple. I need help in the proof of $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$. I tried it in the following way:

Suppose that every associated prime of $I$ that contains $y$ also contains $x.$ I have to prove that $(I:y^{\infty})=(I:(x,y)^{\infty})$.

$(I:y^{\infty})\supset (I:(x,y)^{\infty})$ is trivial. To prove the other inclusion, let $f\in (I:y^{\infty})$, it follows that there exists some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $fy^{n}\in I$. I need to show that $f\in (I:(x,y)^{\infty})$. Here I am stuck how to use the hypothesis and prove it. Please help me.

Comment: This is exercise 15.22 in Eisenbud, *Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(2)\Rightarrow (1)$ Let $I=Q_1\cap\cdots\cap Q_m$ be a minimal primary decomposition of $I$. If $fy^n\in I$, then $fy^n\in Q_i$ for all $i$. If $f\in Q_i$ it's okay. If not, then $y^n\in P_i$, where $P_i=\sqrt{Q_i}$, so $y\in P_i$. By hypothesis $x\in P_i$ and therefore there exists $k_i\ge 1$ such that $x^{k_i}\in Q_i$. Now find a power of $(x,y)$ contained in $Q_i$.

Comment: If $f\in Q_{i}$ for all $i$, we are done. If $f\notin Q_{i}$ for any $i$, we are again done by the argument you gave. What if $f$ doesn't belong to some of $Q_{i}'$s and it belongs to the other.

Comment: Now it is quite clear. Thank you very much.